# Unused properties in application.properties file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

When I tried to connect Spring Boot to the MySQL database there was an issue called: Unused property in the application.properties file.

This is my application.properties file.
[image: application.properties file.]

This is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.fund</groupId>
<artifactId>Slip_Manager</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Slip_Manager</name>
<description>This is a Slip Manager product</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Community doesn't come with support for Spring Boot features, including `application.properties` file syntax. You are getting this warning because IntelliJ IDEA Community thinks it's just a standard Java `.properties` file, which is not referenced in your source code.

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, which is the paid version, [has support for Spring Boot](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should change `spring.jpa.show-sql:true` to `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Database Url
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//database
  //Username
  spring.datasource.username="username"
  //Password
  spring.datasource.password="password"
  //JDBC driver
  spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  //update the table according to entity
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```